# How are emails sent when using for example Outlook Web access (OWA)

Tags: email, outlook, protocols, exchange-server

Nowadays it is also possible to access Emails on the web. The web protocol is Https or just plan Http .

But as everyone learnt emails use protocols like Pop3, Smtp or Imap .

So on the web will there still be used e.g. SMTP to send an email ??

If yes, how will it work. Will the smtp protocol be embedded in the http protocol the same way e.g. SOAP is embedded in http.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, for sending mails the SMTP protocol is used. The server you are accessing via HTTP(S) when using for example OWA will handling this protocol for you.

Basically you as a client using OWA will tell the server (MS Exchange) to send a mail. But the communication between you two is using the HTTP(S) protocol. And as a result of your communication the Exchange Server will use the SMTP protocol as a client to issuing the sending of your email.